# In java `.properties` file is not showing anything in edit mode

Tags: java, properties, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream, properties-file

I'm using `Properties` object with `FileInputStream()` and `FileOutputStream()` method to read/write properties from/into `.properties` file in java.

Its working perfect (I'm able to write and read as well) But when I Open the `.properties` file in editor it shows nothing in it. Its confusing if I'm able to read and write then why values are not showing in that file?

Here is complete code

```
String username = uName.getText().trim();
String pass = uPass.getText().trim();

// Read properties file.
  Properties pro = new Properties();
    try {
        pro.load(new FileInputStream("conf.properties"));
        pro.setProperty("user", username);
        pro.setProperty("pass", pass);
        pro.store(new FileOutputStream("conf.properties"), null);

        String user = pro.getProperty("user");
        System.out.println(user);
        System.out.println("successful .......");

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: My guess is that the file you're looking at in the editor isn't the one you're using for saving/loading. Bear in mind that your code uses a filename relative to your program's current working directory...

Comment: are you running your program from within an IDE? which?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle yes in Netbeans

Comment: In netbeans the *"working"* directory is not the `src` folder. It compiles the *.java  files to the `bin` folder where it also copies any other file from the `src` folder to. Therefore @JonSkeetis right.

Comment: I try with a folder within src

Comment: I create a folder in `src` named "resources" and know i'm using `resources\\conf.properties` instead of `conf.properties` but IDE says 
`"java.io.FileNotFoundException: resources\conf.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)"`

Comment: @JonSkeet you are right it creates a new conf.properties file under the project folder. thanks for pointing out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files are not flushed until you close them.

You have to change your code to include the call to the method .close() on the file input stream and close the output stream too, because the method store makes a call to .flush() but not to close, so your file system will not show you the changes:

```
String username = uName.getText().trim();
String pass = uPass.getText().trim();

// Read properties file.
Properties pro = new Properties();
try {

    final FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("conf.properties");
    pro.load(new FileInputStream("conf.properties"));
    fileInputStream.close();
    pro.setProperty("user", username);
    pro.setProperty("pass", pass);
    String user = pro.getProperty("user");
    System.out.println(user);

    final FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("conf.properties");
    pro.store(fileOutputStream, null);
    fileOutputStream.close();
    System.out.println("successful .......");

} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

You only have to write the code that extract the properties in the format you want to store them. That should do the trick.  (I've coded directly here, sorry if there's a mistake)

EDITING:
I just coded it, it works:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String username = "bla";
    String pass = "blabla";

    // Read properties file.
    Properties pro = new Properties();
    try {
        File file = new File("/tmp/conf.properties");
        file.createNewFile();
        final FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        pro.load(fileInputStream);
        fileInputStream.close();
        pro.setProperty("user", username);
        pro.setProperty("pass", pass);
        String user = pro.getProperty("user");
        System.out.println(user);

        File toClose = new File("/tmp/conf.properties");
        final FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(toClose);
        pro.store(fileOutputStream, null);
        fileOutputStream.close();

        System.out.println("successful .......");

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
cat /tmp/conf.properties 
#Sun Nov 20 18:23:58 CET 2016
user=bla
pass=blabla
```

Maybe the problem resides in other place? try compiling, packaging it and then running it in the terminal (java -jar ...)

Comment: its still the same.

Comment: Check my edditing ;)

Comment: your code is working But there is still nothing in properties file when in editing mode.

Comment: Close it and open it, probably your editor is not fetching data because it is not expecting changes of the file from other applications.

Comment: I think you should read about File systems. Then you will understand why an editor is not loading the changes "on the fly".

Comment: @jonSkeet is right I figured out that it create a new file under the main project folder

Answer (score -2):

> `setProperty` merely updates the set of properties, it does not write the file. You have to call the store(`OutputStream` out, `String` header) method to actually write out the file to disk, and that is the time where you'll have to "lock" the file.

check out accepted answer in  [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647881/lock-properties-file-in-java)

Comment: OP is calling store